# Cannnot get IF ELSE IF statement to work

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I'm trying to get it so that when a user logs in, a trigger checks a specific column. If the column value is 'No', I want it to set it as 'Ask', and if it is already 'Ask', I want it to set it to 'Yes'. Nothing I try seems to work. Most recently I tried:

```
IF( new.eula_accepted =  'No' ) THEN SET new.eula_accepted =  'Ask';
else if( new.eula_accepted =  'Ask' ) THEN SET new.eula_accepted =  'Yes'; 
end if
```

The error it gives me is "MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3". If I try just this:

```
IF( new.eula_accepted =  'No' ) THEN SET new.eula_accepted =  'Ask';
end if
```

*THAT* works just fine, but I really need it to do both. Any help would be appreciated, I'm getting frustrated beyond belief.

Comment: which line is line 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`IF` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) is wrong. Use `ELSEIF` instead of `ELSE IF`:

```
IF new.eula_accepted = 'No' THEN SET new.eula_accepted = 'Ask'; 
ELSEIF new.eula_accepted = 'Ask' THEN SET new.eula_accepted = 'Yes';
END IF;
```